# What fraction of my questions have accepted answers? How can I find out?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a lot of questions here and a great majority have answers, and for a great majority of those an answer has been accepted.

Is it possible for someone to figure out what fraction of my questions have accepted answers without going through the 44 pages of questions and counting?

Is it then possible to explain the procedure to me as if I were a child? I'm not familliar with database queries, anything besides python is a real challenge for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the advanced search features of the normal site - no need for fancy database queries. It's not so easy to find, but there is a little "Advanced Search Tips" whenever you search and some of these features are relevant for you.

> [image: Screenshot of the search bar with the "Advanced Search Tips" highlighted by a red circle]

First you go to your profile on the main site. That's [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/12102/uhoh). As you can see the searchbar is already filled with your user-id. No need to search for that somewhere. The searchbar reads [user:12102](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102), which will give you all posts from you.

Next we want to limit this down to questions. There is a handy way to do this: just add "is:question" or in short "is:q" to the searchbar. Like [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+is%3Aq) (1296 posts from you are questions - impressive!).

Next we want to limit this down to all those with an accepted answer: "hasaccepted:yes" => [user:12102 hasaccepted:yes](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+hasaccepted%3Ayes) (912 of your questions have an accepted answer).

Together those two search queries mean that you have accepted an answer in 912 / 1296 ~ 70% of all cases where you asked a question.

Minor addition: those are only undeleted questions, I don't know if you have deleted ones.

If you want to find those without an accepted answer you can just change the query to "hasaccepted:no" like [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+hasaccepted%3Ano), for example in case you want to search for interesting questions that you want to offer a bounty on.

Comment: "impressive!"? by coincidence I just right now wrote [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49637190#49637190) It's a scourge, my life is an endless series of cups of coffee and pavlovian clicks of the `Post Your Question` button.

Comment: This works very well, and is really easy to use, thank you very much!

Comment: @uhoh Then you are a dream of many smaller sites on the network. Enjoy your cup of cofee and have fun with the advanced search features and your new found question / answer statistics ;)